# Get the index number of a column name with Perl DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

Given this perl DBI query:

```
$qh = $db_connection->prepare ('SELECT addresses.* from addresses WHERE 1');
```

The addresses table structure might change in the future, that is, some new columns may get inserted into it. So there's no guarantee which index number a particular column may get assigned to.

When I do a `$qh->fetchrow_array`, I want to be able to determine what the index number of a particular column is so I can check to see if it's empty. For example, I want to see if the `mail_addr` column is empty  like so:

```
if (!$$row[$index_number]) {
  do_something();
}
```

How can I determine what the value `$index_number` should be?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/simple-database-access-using-perl-dbi-and-sql

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `SELECT *`. Specify the columns you want to return in your SQL statement. Doing otherwise risks breaking your code, as you've figured out.

Comment: Can't spam the uparrow on your comment! ->@ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: What do you want to do if the `mail_addr` column no longer exists?

Comment: You can use the [NAME_lc_hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#NAME_uc_hash) attribute for this. But fetchrow_hashref (suggested in answers below) or [bind_columns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_columns) are almost always a better choice. See the bind_columns example where it binds to the fields of a hash.

Answer (score 3):

This can be determined via [$sth->{NAME}](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#NAME_lc). However, this situation is probably more appropriate for [fetchrow_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#fetchrow_hashref) which implements all the gluing of indices to field names you're looking for:

```
while ( my $row = $qh->fetchrow_hashref ) {
  if (!$row->{mail_addr}) {
    do_something();
  }
}
```

Also consider the [FetchHashKeyName](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#FetchHashKeyName) attribute, [fetchrow_hashref('NAME_lc')](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#fetchrow_hashref), or the [$sth->{NAME_lc}](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#NAME_lc) attribute, which will guarantee the case of fieldnames presented by the DBI.  Different SQL engines will normalize the identifier case differently, often depending on whether the identifier was quoted when declared.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please don't use the `$$row[$index_number]` syntax. Anyone looking at your code will be expecting to see that written as `$row->[$index_number]`.

You've worked out why `SELECT *` is a bad idea. So don't do that. List the specific columns that you are interested in - that way you can impose your own order (`fetchrow_array` returns columns in the order that they appear in the SELECT clause).

Alternatively, switch to one of the hash-based fetch methods like `fetchrow_hashref`.

But the best alternative would be to look at using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/release/DBIx-Class).